# Exchange Web Services (EWS) - Appointment Resources

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I managed to create an appointment to an impersonate account with EWS command-lines.

But I want to include a room (Exchange Room Mailbox) as Resource / Location.

In my script I've added the two command-lines below :

- `$NewAppointment.Location($RoomName)`
- `$NewAppointment.Resources.Add($RoomMail)`

**`$RoomName`** and **`$RoomMail`** are found by the **`Get-MailBox`** command-lines :

- `$Room = Get-MailBox $CSV.Room`
- `$RoomName = $Room.DisplayName`
- `$RoomMail = $Room.UserPrincipalName or $Room.PrimarySmtpAddress`

Edit :

I've added the following block of code :

```
$NewGuid = newGuid
$LocationURIGuid = $NewGuid.Guid
$LocationURI = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition($LocationURIGuid, "LocationUri", [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::String)
$NewAppointment.SetExtendedProperty($LocationURI,$RoomMail)

$NewGuid = newGuid
$LocationSourceGuid = $NewGuid.Guid
$LocationSource = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition($LocationSourceGuid, "LocationSource", [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Integer)
$NewAppointment.SetExtendedProperty($LocationSource,5)

$NewGuid = newGuid
$LocationDisplayNameGuid = $NewGuid.Guid
$LocationDisplayName = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition($LocationSourceGuid, "LocationDisplayName", [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Integer)
$NewAppointment.SetExtendedProperty($LocationDisplayName,$Room)
```

newGuid is a function :

```
function newGuid() { return [guid]::NewGuid() }
```

The error is :

> Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "ExtendedPropertyDefinition" and the argument count: "3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use Load() to reload the appointment once you have created it and then you should see those properties filled out.That information is popualted when the appointment is created and not returned in the CreateItem operation so won't appear until you make another GetItem request.

Edit

You need to add this information using Extended properties as EWS won't do it for you eg

```
        Guid PropGuid = Guid.Parse("{A719E259-2A9A-4FB8-BAB3-3A9F02970E4B}");
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition LocationURI = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(PropGuid, "LocationUri", MapiPropertyType.String);
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition LocationSource = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(PropGuid, "LocationSource", MapiPropertyType.Integer);
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition LocationDisplayName = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(PropGuid, "LocationDisplayName", MapiPropertyType.String);
        newapt.SetExtendedProperty(LocationURI, "Somewhere@domain.com");
        newapt.SetExtendedProperty(LocationSource, 5);
        newapt.SetExtendedProperty(LocationDisplayName, "Somewhere");
```

Edit 2 powershell code

```
$PropGuid = [Guid]::Parse("{A719E259-2A9A-4FB8-BAB3-3A9F02970E4B}")
    $LocationURI = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition($PropGuid, "LocationUri", [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::String)
    $NewAppointment.SetExtendedProperty($LocationURI,$RoomMail)

    $LocationSource = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition($PropGuid, "LocationSource", [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Integer)
    $NewAppointment.SetExtendedProperty($LocationSource,5)

    $LocationDisplayName = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition($PropGuid, "LocationDisplayName", 

    [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Integer)
    $NewAppointment.SetExtendedProperty($LocationDisplayName,$Room)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The fact is Load() or not the room I've added is not seen like a room.
In command-line or in web app the Location is always shown as an address.

Comment: Can you add some clarification in your question as your don't give enough detail or code for anybody to answer

Comment: OK. Sorry :)
When I want to create a meeting/appointment to an impersonate account with room as a Resource/Location I use the $NewAppointment.Resources.Add($Room) command-line. This command add a Resource but this one is not shown as a real room.
The result on Outlook OWA is that the Location entry is shown as a classic place (Bing search) and not like a room.

Comment: EWS won't add this information you need to set it via some extended properties see my above edit

Comment: Thank your for your information. Do you have the same code in PowerShell ?

Comment: No you should try first to convert it yourself so you learn something then ask for help with what you can't get to work

Comment: I've searched by myself but I'm blocked... I've updated my post ! Thank you.

Comment: The propset GUID must be set the way I have demonstrated otherwise the property will have no meaning see the example in edit 2

Comment: Thank you ! The script is completely operational